# IWebJobsStartup with Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to create an azure function with V2 runtime through visual studio and CLI. But when i run it, i see the following error:

> [9/30/2018 3:11:06 PM] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Following is the azure function run time and core tool version

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.3)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12115.0

Also i have installed the service bus extension

[image]

I have also tried to install the extension through CLI too. Following is the project.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>V2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.22" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note - This is out of the box template and no changes have been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />
```

Please remove this package reference and clean the project, it has been imported in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` for VS development. Import it again may cause building error like you have seen.

**Update**

Since you don't see `function.json` in built assets, I am afraid there is something wrong with `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` on your side, which fails to build trigger attribute in .cs file to `function.json`. My suggestion is

1. Delete Function SDK `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions`.
2. Delete Function CLI using by VS `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools`.
3. Delete template engine consumed by VS `%userprofile%\.templateengine`.
4. Restart VS and create a new Function project, at the bottom of the creation/template dialog, see `Making sure all templates are up to date`. Wait until it changes to `Updates are ready`.
   [image]
   [image]
5. Click `Refresh`.

Just in case you need to check, I use the Service Bus queue trigger template in VS. The code is as below, .csproj is same as the one in question without `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator`.

```
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    namespace FunctionApp1
    {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [FunctionName("Function1")]
            public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "MyConnection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the folder structure in `[Functionproject]\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jerry Liu. But the issue still remains as I still see the same error when I run the function

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Sorry for my omission, you also need to clean your project first.

Comment: Yes. I had done a clean and then built it again. I also tried it in release mode. Its the same issue.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Looks like you generate the template using CLI, right? Have you tried to create it using VS directly? You need to install [this extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version).

Comment: Apologies. As mentioned in my question, I have tried both. VS and CLI also I have performed the steps mentioned to register the extensions. Let me know if you need me to share the sample

Comment: @GurpreetSingh Hmm..I have created service bus queue trigger using both VS and CLI, works without changes except adding connection strings. Check whether there's a `function.json` in a folder named after your function, under [Functionproject]\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0 folder.

Comment: Please share the project you created and no, the function.json is not present. I only see dlls here including host.json and local.settings.json.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh See whether my update works for you, sorry that I can't repro your problem so my suggestion may not be useful.

Comment: Cleaning up those folders seems to have resolved the issue.